# Why doesnt WinMinimize work in autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I've been trying to make a macro for my survival single player Minecraft world.

I used some stuff from youtube, google and used many stuff to make it into a script (i used a free version of some youtubers ahk script and rewrote everything except gui). All the stuff work normally, except one thing: WinMinimize. When I press f7, I made it so it minimizes the window, but instead of minimizing it, it just closes it. I googled alot, searched it on here too but couldnt find it. How can I fix it so it can work? Here's the code, thanks!

```
Menu, Tray, NoIcon

#SingleInstance, force
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
 
Gui, Color, black
Gui, Font, S8 CWhite, Verdana
Gui, Font, S20 CDefault, Asinastra
Gui, Font, S20 CDefault, Asinastra
Gui, Font, S16 CDefault, Asinastra
Gui, Font, S14 CDefault, Asinastra
Gui, Font, S20 CWhite, Asinastra
Gui, Add, Text, x48 y19 w350 h30 +Center, carrot macro
Gui, Font, S18 CWhite, Asinastra
Gui, Add, GroupBox, x562 y-1 w-30 h170 , GroupBox
Gui, Font, S16 CWhite, Asinastra
Gui, Add, GroupBox, x28 y69 w390 h150 , Config
Gui, Font, S14 CWhite, Asinastra
Gui, Add, Text, x100 y139 w190 h30, f8 - turn on
Gui, Add, Text, x100 y169 w210 h30, f9 - exit
Gui, Add, Text, x100 y109 w190 h30, f7 - minimize
Gui, Font, S18 CWhite, Asinastra
Gui, Add, GroupBox, x28 y239 w390 h170 , Info
Gui, Font, S20 CDefault, Asinastra
Gui, Font, S20 CDefault, Asinastra
Gui, Font, S16 CDefault, Asinastra
Gui, Font, S14 CDefault, Asinastra
Gui, Font, S18 CBlack, Asinastra
Gui, Font, S12 CWhite, Asinastra
Gui, Add, Text, x322 y429 w120 h30
Gui, Font, S16 CWhite, Asinastra
Gui, Font, S14 CWhite, Asinastra
Gui, Font, S14 CWhite, Asinastra
Gui, Add, Text, x42 y309 w360 h30 , carrot farm :D


Gui, Show, x304 y107 h488 w451, Carrot farm macro
Return


Gui, Show, x304 y107 h488 w451,
Return
GuiClose:
ExitApp

f7::
WinMinimize

f9::
ExitApp


f8::
Gui, Submit, NoHide
Loop
{
SetKeyDelay, 50, 50
Controlsend,, {v down}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep 100
Controlsend,, {o down}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep 100
Controlsend,, {w down}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep 1500
Controlsend,, {w up}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep 100
Controlsend,, {a down}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep 43500
Controlsend,, {a up}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep 100
Controlsend,, {o up}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep 100
Controlsend,, {w down}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep 1500
Controlsend,, {w up}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep 100
Controlsend,, {o down}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep 100
Controlsend,, {d down}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep 43500
Controlsend,, {d up}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep 50
Controlsend,, {v up}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep 50
Controlsend,, {o up}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep 50
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add return at the end like this:

```
f7::
WinMinimize
Return

f9::
ExitApp
Return
```

or change it like this if it's only one command:

```
f7::WinMinimize
```

add return at the end of f8 as well so it won't jump to next lines in case you add more lines